# Difference when building VS solution in VS and msbuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, csc

I've also posted this as an [issue in github](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/417) for the msbuild project.

I'm having an issue building some projects. I´ve found differences between building my solutions in VS (it work fine), and building the solutions with msbuild through command line (it fails).

I've managed to make a small sample that illustrates the problem. [BuildError.zip](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/files/77337/BuildError.zip)

Basically I've got 2 solutions `SolA.sln` and `SolAandB.sln`. `SolA.sln` only contains project `A.csproj` while `SolAandB.sln` contains both `A.csproj` and `B.csproj`. The project `A.csproj` is just a class library, while `B.csproj` is a command line project which references project `A.csproj`. The **subtle peculiarity** about this projects, is that `A.csproj` is configured to not be built in `SolAandB.sln`. The reason of this, is that I've got a lot of projects (more than 300, some of which are C# and others are C++ managed and unmanaged), and some projects are included in more than one solution (mainly to allow adding references to the project), but I only want to build the project once.

When I build `SolAandB.sln` in VS (I'm using `VS2015` with update 1, but don't believe that changes anything), I can see that the invocation to `csc.exe` for `B.csproj` is as follows (I've added line breaks between arguments for clarity):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe
 /noconfig
 /nowarn:1701,1702,2008
 /nostdlib+
 /platform:anycpu32bitpreferred
 /errorreport:prompt
 /warn:4
 /define:DEBUG;TRACE
 /errorendlocation
 /preferreduilang:en-US
 /highentropyva+
 /reference:"F:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BuildError\A\bin\Debug\A.dll"
 /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\mscorlib.dll"
 /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Core.dll"
 /debug+
 /debug:full
 /filealign:512
 /optimize-
 /out:obj\Debug\B.exe
 /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset"
 /subsystemversion:6.00
 /target:exe
 /utf8output
 Program.cs
 Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
 "C:\Users\Fede\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
 obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs
 obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs
 obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs
```

Note the `/reference:"F:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BuildError\A\bin\Debug\A.dll"` which points correctly to the output of `A.csproj` for the selected build configuration. If I had built in `Release`, the reference would have correctly pointed to the release build output of `A.csproj`.

The result of that build depends on having `A.csproj` already built, which I have. You can see a sample build script in `BuildSolutions.proj` which first builds `SolA.sln` and then `SolAandB.sln`.

Now if I build `SolAandB.sln` through the command line, or as a result of building `BuildSolutions.proj`, I can see that the invocation to `csc.exe` for `B.csproj` is as follows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe
 /noconfig
 /nowarn:1701,1702
 /nostdlib+
 /platform:anycpu32bitpreferred
 /errorreport:prompt
 /warn:4
 /define:DEBUG;TRACE
 /highentropyva+
 /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\mscorlib.dll"
 /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Core.dll"
 /debug+
 /debug:full
 /filealign:512
 /optimize-
 /out:obj\Debug\B.exe
 /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset"
 /subsystemversion:6.00
 /target:exe
 /utf8output
 Program.cs
 Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
 "C:\Users\Fede\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
```

As you can see, beside several apparently subtle differences, the biggest difference is in that the argument `/reference:"F:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BuildError\A\bin\Debug\A.dll"` is missing, and thus the project fails to build with the error `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'A' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`.

## Question

How can I build the solution, in a way that when `csc.exe` is invoked, it's invoked the same way as when I'm building the solution inside visual studio?

Comment: Until this is fixed you probably can't. MsBuild transforms the solution into an MsBuild project and that project invokes almost the same targets as VS does, but due to subtle differences in the ResolveProjectReferences target (e.g. the `BuildingInsideVisualStudio` isn't set etc) the reference is not considered. You could pass `OnlyReferenceAndBuildProjectsEnabledInSolutionConfiguration=False` to the build but then A will be built as well. Or you could build B.csproj in which case the reference is resolved correctly but then you're not building the solution.

Comment: Really hoped I could work this out, as VS uses msbuild itself to build solutions. I had see the `BuildingInsideVisualStudio` property, and tried setting it when invoking the msbuild for the solution files, but didn't have any luck either.

Comment: No tyhere's more going on. I had a quick look at Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets where the ResolveProjectReferences target resides but didn't immediately see how to make it do what you want and I don't have the time atm - I'm 90% sure it should be possible though, key is getting the `_ResolvedProjectReferencePaths` ItemGroup populated with the correct reference